# Best way to present the user the XML values of a file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-serialization

I got a XML File, looking familiar to this :

```
<root>
 <carnumber>12</carnumber>
 <carcolor>2</carcolor>
 <cartype>5</cartype>
</root>
```

Like you see I got some Elements with values/text in it. The car element for example can take values from 1 to 1000. But the element carcolor can take values from 1 - 5 and the cartype from 1 - 10.

The important thing is that the values of the carcolor and cartype elements mean something. carcolor "2" means red, "1" blue and so on.

So I need to present the user not the values but the real meaning of the values.

I found myself creating some classes that represent the elements with there valid values and things got really complicated and I dont know if this was/is the best way.

A friend of mine suggested me to use XML serialization because my XML file is static. It will never change.

My question is simple. I just wanna know how you would solve this problem. My idea contains classes that represent the XML element, for example cartype within this class I have a Dictonary with a  pair. This represent the values within the XML file and the string is the meaning of this value. And I use a lot of Linq to navigate and edit the values.

Thanks again!

Comment: Also I must give the User the chance to edit this values and like you know in a user friendly way. That means if the user wants to edit the color, I must represent all colors that are valid. Like a combobox with values like : "Blue", "Red" .... but than I must generate again a valid XML from it.

Comment: The XML file is so given. I cant do any changes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Car
{
    private static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));

    [XmlElement("carnumber")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("carcolor")]
    public int Color { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cartype")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CarColor CarColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (CarColor)Color;
        }
        set
        {
            Color = (int)value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CarType CarType
    {
        get
        {
            return (CarType)Type;
        }
        set
        {
            Type = (int)value;
        }
    }

    public string CarColorString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CarColor.ToString().Replace('_', ' ');
        }
    }

    public string CarTypeString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CarType.ToString().Replace('_', ' ');
        }
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static Car Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return (Car)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}

public enum CarColor
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Green = 3,
    Light_Brown = 4
    // and so on...
}

public enum CarType
{
    Sedan = 1,
    Coupe = 2,
    Hatchback = 3,
    SUV = 4,
    Pickup_Truck = 5
    // and so on...
}
```

I've added some enums to allow for presentation.

You can set the values of a Car and serialize it to an xml string:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.Number = 1;
car.CarColor = CarColor.Blue;
car.CarType = CarType.Coupe;
string xml = car.Serialize();
```

And deserialize an xml string into a car:

```
string example = 
@"<root>
 <carnumber>12</carnumber>
 <carcolor>2</carcolor>
 <cartype>5</cartype>
</root>";

Car car = Car.Deserialize(example);
```

For presentation, you can use the CarColorString and CarTypeString properties, which, in case your enum values contain more than one word, replace underscores with spaces.

```
Console.WriteLine(car.CarColorString);
Console.WriteLine(car.CarTypeString);
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be as complicated or easy as you want it to be. I would, however, second your friends suggestion to use XML Serialization, something like:

```
[XmlRoot("Car")]
public class Car
{
     public Car() 
     {
     }

     [XmlElement("Number")]
     public int Number { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("Color")]
     public int Color { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("Type")]
     public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.Number = 1;
myCar.Color = 2;
myCar.Type = 3;

XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
TextWriter w = new StreamWriter( @"c:\Car.xml" );
s.Serialize(w, myCar);
w.Close();
```

Deserialization:

```
Car myCar;
TextReader r = new StreamReader("Car.xml");
myCar = (Car)s.Deserialize(r);
r.Close();
```

You could further improve this by exposing a custom enum for the likes of your `Type` field and internally serializing the number relating to it. Also perhaps exposing the `Color` enum for the car and internally storing a numerical value.

Comment: This would help me to load and save the file, yes. But what about the presentation of the data ?

Comment: It depends on how you are implementing your forms. However, as basic as you can get, just display the values in Labels to start off with.

Comment: For Color you can create enum for above given solution.

Comment: Also depends if it needs to be internationalized or if it's English only

Answer (score 0):

Why not format your XML file more like:

```
<root>
 <carnumber code="2" name="John's Car"/>
 <carcolor code="3" name="Red"/>
 <cartype code="2" name="Hatchback"/>
</root>
```

Comment: The XML file is so given. I cant do any changes on it. But with a XSLT I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would build the UI in WPF, not WinForms.  Set up a data context that binds to the XML as an XML data source, write type converters to round trip the data between the internal and human-readable values, bind combo boxes to the various elements, and Bob's your uncle.

I recognize that this answer isn't very useful to you if you're not using WPF.